# Should I use for .NET Logging in Azure: AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics or AddApplicationInsights?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, logging, azure-application-insights

I'd like to have custom logging in my code, which will be hosted in Azure.
I've found two extensions for logging providers, between which I am not sure what is the difference.

The two providers that I'm using in my `program.cs`:

```
builder.Logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
builder.Logging.AddApplicationInsights();
```

I tried to comment either and in Azure's logs the trace is still the same. Any idea what is the difference between the two and which one should I stick to?

Comment: But it seems like I could find the logs from Application Insights with using `AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> builder.Logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();

- By using  `AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics` Method, we can add an Azure Diagnostics logger and can get the diagnostic logs in Azure App Service.
- we need to configure file logger options in `Program.cs` file.
- Install the NuGet Package  `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`.
- In `Program.cs` file, add the below lines of code to configure diagnostic logs.

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices;
builder.Logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
builder.Services.Configure<AzureFileLoggerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.FileName = "Diagnostics-Logs";
    options.FileSizeLimit = 50 * 1024;
    options.RetainedFileCountLimit = 3;
});
```

- Build and deploy the App to Azure App service.
- In `Azure App service` => `App Service Logs` => enable `Application logging (Filesystem)`.

[image]

- After enabling the filesystem, In Kudu console logs are created in a new file under `D:\home\LogFiles\Application` path.

[image]

> builder.Logging.AddApplicationInsights();

AddApplicationInsights() method is to configure `Application Insights` for Azuer App Service.

- Install the NuGet package  `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights`.
- AddApplicationInsights() requires LogLevel .It is not mentioned,by default it takes `LogLevel.Warning`.

In `Program.cs` file, add the below code.

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights;
builder.Logging.AddApplicationInsights();
```

***Controller***

```cs
 [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            _logger.LogTrace("Trace Log");
            _logger.LogDebug("Debug Log");
            _logger.LogInformation("Information Log");
            _logger.LogWarning("Warning Log");
            _logger.LogError("Error Log");
            _logger.LogCritical("Critical Log");

            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
```

***Application Insights***
[image]

References taken from [AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#azure-app-service) and [AddApplicationInsights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger#example-programcs)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! so in short one saves the logs in a file system and the other saves it in trace application insights table, is this correct? Is there any other different between the two types of logs?

Comment: Yes..exactly..this is the main difference what I have observed.