# Viewing Logs in Azure for AppService

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-log-analytics, azure-diagnostics

Hi I have simple application where I want to implement the logs so when the error occured I can view the error in a file in Azure.

I read some article they do describe to view the error monitoring.  What I actually want to see the error that are added into some file. So when there an error occured in a deployed app, I should be able to go to the log file and read the error or information.

Simple enough I have created a new ASP.NET 6 API which comes wiht the Ilogger.   Now cosider if I deploy this app to the Azure and if there is an error how I can see it in a file?

--Above is my original question. After implemenation the proposed solution I am still unable to view the log file or logs any where in the Azure. please see the code and images. I have verified locally in console the information and error are being logged but not showing up in any where in azure.

appsettings.

[image]

program.cs

[image]

information log and error log

[image]

Azure filelog is enabled
[image]

Folder in kudu not found.
[image]

WebConfig
[image]

Comment: We can log the traces /errors/requests to a file in the KUDU Logfiles folder by using `AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics`.Will pos tan answer in detail.

Comment: Check that txt files under logfiles application

Comment: @Harshitha, I did check in logfiles\Application folder there is no log file.  you can also see the image that I sent. It is showing the files under logfiles.   Are you referering to another location?

Comment: I have asked the orignal question few months back since the priorities changed I could not implment the proposed solution until few days ago.  Then, I have posted all my code and waiting for help. But not much.  So should I create a new question or wait here for reply?

Comment: Yes,please raise a new question stating your current issues in detail.Will check it.

Comment: Please check the comments in the newly posted question

Answer (score 0):

When we deploy `.NET Core App` to `Azure App service` (using `Visual Studio Publish option`/`GitHub Actions`/`VS Publish Import Profile`), by default `Web.config` file will be generated in the deployment process.

- You can check it in the application root directory `site/wwwroot`.

[image]

- The easiest way to check the logs in a file is by changing the `stdoutLogEnabled` value to `true`.
- Open the `web.config` file by clicking on edit button.
- After updating the `stdoutLogEnabled` value. Run the application. If there are any errors/unable to access the deployed URL, a file with clear error info will be generated in `Logfiles` folder.

***Path:*** - `C:\home\LogFiles`

[image]

- New file will be generated after every deployment when you run the application.

[image]

Check the `Note section` in the [SOThread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77359601/19648279) to work with `web.config` locally.

***Using `AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics`:***

As mentioned in the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#azure-app-service),

> By using AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics, we can write logs to text files in an Azure App Service app's file system

Refer first section in the [SOthread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74545374/19648279) which I have posted.

In `App Service logs`,enable the `Application logging` and change the Logging level to `Error`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am not able to create log files after updating the webconfig file.  However, I was able to create a log file with the AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics  that only shows the error but I am unable to see any logInformation just the error messages furthermore I can't see any error from the Azure portal under logStream.

Comment: Have you enabled Application logging?

Comment: Can you please share your source code?

Comment: sorry to get back to you a bit late but nw I am back to work on the logs. So tested your solution it is not working I am updating the orignal post after the implemenation.